# Prove $R_1\circ R_2=A^2\iff R_2\circ R_1=A^2.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

> Suppose $A$ is a set and let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be two equivalence relations on $A$. Prove $R_1\circ R_2=A^2\iff R_2\circ R_1=A^2.$

**My attempt:**

This is what I have, but I got stuck. I tried to prove $R_1\circ R_2=A^2\implies R_2\circ R_1=A^2$ by contradiction. The converse should be analogous.

Suppose $R_1\circ R_2=A^2$ and $R_2\circ R_1\ne A^2.$

$R_2\circ R_1\ne A^2\implies\exists (x,y)\in A^2, (x,y)\notin(R_2\circ R_2).$

By definition, $(x,y)\in R_2\circ R_1\iff \exists z\in A, (x,z)\in R_1\land (z,y)\in R_2,$ so
$(x,y)\notin (R_2\circ R_2)\iff \forall z\in A, (x,z)\notin R_1\lor (z,y)\notin R_2.$ Since $R_1$ and $R_2$ are reflexive as equivalence relations, for $z=x$ and $z=y,$ we get $(x,y)\notin R_1$ and $(y,x)\notin R_2.$

Comment: Proving this by contradiction is difficult because there isn't really anywhere to go from $(x,y) \notin (R_2 \circ R_1)$. Instead, show $A^2 \subseteq R_2 \circ R_1$ directly. Given $(a_1,a_2) \in A^2$, we know $(a_1,a_2) \in R_1 \circ R_2$, ... or maybe $(a_2,a_1) \in R_1 \circ R_2$?

Comment: You don’t need contradiction. Try unraveling what it means for every ordered pair to be in the composite, and use the properties of an equivalence relation.

Comment: $\forall x,z \;\exists y, R_1(x,y) \land  R_2(y,z) $

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, so, given $(a_1,a_2)\in A^2,$ we know $(a_2,a_1)\in A^2=R_1\circ R_2,$ but $(a_2,a_1)\in R_1\circ R_2\iff (a_1,a_2)\in R_2\circ R_1, $ (since $(a_2,a_1)\in R_1\circ R_2\implies \exists a_3\in A, a_2R_2a_3R_1a_1\implies a_1R_1a_3R_2a_2$ by symmetry) is that the reasoning?

Comment: I think you're on the right track! Why don't you write an answer?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow up on Matthew's hint:

Suppose $R_1\circ R_2=A^2$ for equivalence relations $R_1,R_2$ on a set $A$. Let $(a_1,a_2)\in A^2.$ Then, $(a_2,a_1)\in A^2,$ too, but $A^2=R_1\circ R_2$ by the assumption, so $\exists a_3\in A$ such that $a_2R_2a_3R_1a_1.$ As $R_1$ and $R_2$ are equivalence relations, hence symmetric, we obtain $a_1R_1a_3R_2a_2,$ that is, $(a_1,a_2)\in R_2\circ R_1.$ Therefore, $A^2\subseteq R_2\circ R_1.$

$R_2\circ R_1\subseteq A^2$ holds by definition.

And the converse statement in the task follows analogously.